# Nested functions in python

Tags: python, function

I have a function that makes a dictionary based on file input. Then another function that makes a calculation based on the dictionary. These 2 functions are nested in a main function. I.e:

```
def make_dic():
     data=dict()
     code...
     return data
def make_calculation():
     for x,y in data.items()
     code....
def main():
    data=make_dic()
    make_calculation()
```

My problem is that I get an error:
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

How can I get make_calculation() recognize the dictionary created in make_dic() when they are nested in main()?

Thanks.

Comment: pass it as an argument to `make_calculation`?

Comment: Python is *lexically* (or statically) scoped. `make_calculations` looks in the scope where it is *defined*, not the scope where it is *called*, for a definition of the free variable `data`.

Comment: ("Nested function" usually refers to a function *defined* in another function, not just one that is called in another.)

Comment: There are *dynamically* scoped languages (shells like `bash`, Lisp, etc), but lexical scoping is widely considered to be easier to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass "data" as a parameter to your make_calculation function:

```
def make_dic():
     data=dict()
     code...
     return data
def make_calculation(data):
     for x,y in data.items()
     code....
def main():
    data=make_dic()
    make_calculation(data)
```

The reason you need to do this is due to Python scoping rules (i.e. the location within a program , or "scope" of where a parameter is or is not defined).

Parameter "data" is not a global variable (***using global variables is rarely recommended and should be a last resort***) , and thus make_calculation(data) needs to receive the element as a parameter, which was defined elsewhere -ultimately the parameter created in make_dic()

@chepner said as much, more formally, in their comment (i.e. Python is lexically scoped). For much more on Python scoping rules see this old, but still useful ,answer : [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 0):

in the first function try putting global data, hope it helps.